# Awk printing more records than are in original file

Tags: awk

I have written matches.awk to print from each line of a text file the text which matches my regular expression.

```
`{
    line = $0
    while (match(line, /([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))[[:space:]]?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})/)>0) {

       print substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH)
       line = substr(line, RSART + RLENGTH) }}`
```

which I then call with

`awk -f matches.awk file.txt`

It is printing the data correctly but strangely is printing some records far more frequently than they appear in the text file.

This one record which is a line in file.txt '20 Lilac Grove, Leeds LS5 3AG, Lilac Grove' appears four times as many times (212) as it is in file.txt (53). Any idea why this is?

Comment: 'pe19 1lr' on the other hand appears 7 times in file.txt and is accordingly printed just 7 times

Comment: Presumably that regexp matches that string in 4 different places?

Comment: The new line variable inside the loop is not being set correctly due to a typo `substr(line, RSART + RLENGTH) }`. Check the response I've posted.

Comment: @user1893110, it will be better if you could post sample of input and sample of expected output in your post too, to get a better understanding of your question.

Comment: Run `gawk --lint 'your script' file` and it outputs `gawk: cmd. line:6: (FILENAME=file FNR=1) warning: reference to uninitialized variable 'RSART'` which is a big clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your code (RSART instead of RSTART).

It should be:

```
 {
    line = $0
    while (match(line, /([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))[[:space:]]?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})/)>0) {

       print substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH)
       line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH) }}
```

Just tested and seems to be OK (i.e: the regexp will hit your line once).

Anyway, I'm afraid you don't understand how your code is working. Please check the [String functions GAWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) page and see what match() and substr() actually do and what they return.

Comment: Wow careless mistake by me. Good spot.

Yes I need to brush up further. Thanks